# How to write text above and below \iff so that it works with breqn?

Tags: programming, overset

`breqn` makes the following code not work in one of my latex files, and I am not sure how to code it differently so that it works with `breqn` loaded as I need this package for other things. Here is the problem

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}%ext
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}  
\begin{document}
\[
A  \overset{Forward}{\underset{inverse}{\iff}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

This gives the error

```
Undefined control sequence. A \overset{Forward}{\underset{inverse}{\iff}}
```

Removing `breqn`, it compiles ok `lualatex foo.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is what I tried

```
  A  \iff^{Forward}_{inverse} B
  A  \overset{Forward}{\iff}_{inverse} B
```

And I give up. I am not good at Latex.

Is there a different way to code this that give similar result, but also when `breqn` is loaded?

TL 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `\iff`, you can use an extensible arrow from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (which loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), and should therefore be compatible with  your example):

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  A \overset{Forward}{\underset{inverse}{\iff}} B \qquad 
  A \xLeftrightarrow[\text{inverse}]{\text{forward}} B
\]

\end{document}
```